# How to connect to kafka and replicate data?

Tags: apache-kafka

The client gave the data bootstrap.servers, login, password and name of the topic. How can I connect to the server with this data? I tried to connect via GUI Conduktor indicated different options: username = "" password = "" and so user = "" password = "", ssl.user = "" ssl.password = ""

In general, I tried many options, it did not work out (authentication error)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use kafka tool.Link is below.

https://www.kafkatool.com/download/?C=S;O=A

Or you can connect through the programming client in any supported language(java,python etc).